# Update textviews properties from service

Tags: android

I have created a bar over all screens(by WindowManager) with 3 TextViews. I have created a service and start a thread and this thread update TextViews over bar in every 1 second(If screen is On). And a Preference Activity which update the properties(like text color, font size, background color, bar position, bar width, bar height etc) of these TextViews over bar. This bar is still visible when I open the Preference Activity. So when I change the proprties of TextViews from Preference Activity the change must be reflect on bar instantly. 
So what is the best way to update the TextViews from Preference Activity(When preference values gets changed)?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a broadcast intent that your service is listening for and whenever it receives such an intent, it knows that it needs to re-read the preferences and update the display appropriately.  Then, in your preference activity, whenever an appropriate value change is recognized, you could fire off that broadcast intent (see [`sendBroadcast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29)).

Comment: But I have to define so many broadcast actions in my case. Is this right to define more then 25 action(for each property of text view)  and a method(to update textview property) for each action?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your use case is, but based on my understanding, if I were doing something similar, I would probably just create a single broadcast action. Whenever the service receives that broadcast, it would read all of the preferences to see which one(s) have changed.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the best solution